# Компиляция Kivy под Винду (проблема с *.spec

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, pyinstaller

Написал сдельную программку на kivy.

И хотел её перевести в виндовый формат *.exe.

Но, как не искал, сдельного *.spec не нашёл под python 3.7.6, было только под 2.7.

Кучу времени уже калебаюсь с PyInstaller, может, кто-то опытный и знакомый с kivy, подсказать дельный  *.spec .

Помогите мне научится грамотно компелировать хотяб 1 файл.

[image: А то все время ересть какае-то компилируется:]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/tree/master/kivymd/tools/packaging/pyinstaller

Comment: Xyanight, выглядит не плохо, только я, как новичок, немного не понимаю как это работает и как может помочь, можете ,пожалуйста, кратко пояснить.